# How to count the 'number of time a field is edited or updated' in Odoo 8?

Tags: python, count, field, odoo, odoo-8

I want to count how many times a field is edited in a form, the count should be passed to another field called 'Number of Edits' in the same form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code Works fine..

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    quotation_obj=self.browse(cr, uid, ids,context=context)
    if partner_id:
                count = quotation_obj.number_of_edits + 1
                vals.update({'number_of_edits': count})

    return super(sale_order, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
```

This is the Entire Code

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
        partner_id=vals.get('partner_id')
        quotation_obj=self.browse(cr, uid, ids,context=context)

        if not partner_id:
            #if partner id not found, find the employee ids
            emp_ids=vals.get('employee_ids')
            if emp_ids:
#                 for line in emp_ids:
#                     employee_ids=line[2]
#             else:#update the employee ids
#                 employee_ids=quotation_obj.employee_ids
                for line in emp_ids:
                    self.pool.get('res.partner').write(cr, uid, quotation_obj.partner_id.id, {'employee_ids': [(4, line[2])]}, context=context)
        if partner_id:
            emp_ids=vals.get('employee_ids')
            if emp_ids:
                for line in emp_ids:
                    self.pool.get('res.partner').write(cr, uid, partner_id, {'employee_ids': [(4, line[2])]}, context=context)

        if partner_id:
            count = quotation_obj.number_of_edits + 1
            vals.update({'number_of_edits': count})

        return super(sale_order, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
```

Comment: That isn't enough if you have a write on multiple ids/records. And where is `partner_id` is coming from?

Comment: aside from `partner_id` why wouldn't be enough. it gets particular record to be updated and updates the count doesn't it?